# rails how to save date_select field value in date field in db

Tags: date, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a date_select in my form:

```
<%= f.date_select :birthdate, {:start_year => Time.now.year - 100} %>
```

I have a field

```
t.date "birthdate"
```

How can I save the value selected in date_select to the database (@user.birthdate)? (without using any gems like datepicker)

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @Pavan I do not understand yet how to save it in the model. I see in params the date is like birthdate(1i): '2015'   birthdate(2i): '3'  birthdate(3i): '14'    but when I try to retrieve it like params[:user][:birthdate(1i)] it showes me a syntax error syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']' user.birthdate = params[:user][:birthdate(1i)] ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try saving it like this

```
@user.brithdate = Date.new(params[:user]["birthdate(1i)"].to_i,params[:user]["birthdate(2i)"].to_i,params[:user]["birthdate(3i)"].to_i)
@user.save
```

Comment: This now works seamlessly, as long as you have the `DATE` type as the OP has done.